# Python - multithreading - Threads terminate in one case. In another they don't. Why?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, queue

Consider the following example I've been doing to learn multithreading. It's just an extended example of the [Python 3.5 queue documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/queue.html).

It prints some numbers over 4 threads, produces one error in the queue, retries this element and should print the remaining queue if a KeyboardInterrupt exception occurs.

```
import threading
import queue
import time
import random
import traceback


def worker(q, active):
    while True:
        worker_item = q.get()
        #if worker_item == None:
        if not active.is_set():
            break
        time.sleep(random.random())
        with threading.Lock():
            if worker_item == 5 or worker_item == '5':
                try:
                    print(threading.current_thread().name + ': ' + worker_item + ' | remaining queue: ' + str(list(q.queue)))
                except TypeError:
                    print(threading.current_thread().name + ': ')
                    print(traceback.format_exc())
                    q.put(str(worker_item))
            else:
                print(threading.current_thread().name + ': ' + str(worker_item) + ' | remaining queue: ' + str(list(q.queue)))
        q.task_done()


def main():

    # INITIALIZE
    num_threads = 4
    stack1 = list(range(1, 21))
    stack2 = list(range(101, 121))
    q = queue.Queue()
    active = threading.Event()
    active.set()

    # START THREADS
    threads = []
    for _ in range(num_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(q, active))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    try:

        # PUT STACK ITEMS ON QUEUE AND BLOCK UNTIL ALL TASKS ARE DONE
        for stack1_item in stack1:
            q.put(stack1_item)
        q.join()
        for stack2_item in stack2:
            q.put(stack2_item)
        q.join()

        # STOP WORKER LOOP IN EVERY THREAD
        #for _ in threads:
            #q.put(None)
        active.clear()

        # WAIT UNTIL ALL THREADS TERMINATE
        for t in threads:
            t.join()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        print('remaining queue: ' + str(list(q.queue)))
        #for _ in threads:
            #q.put(None)
        active.clear()
        for t in threads:
            t.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I run the script as it is (without a KeyboardInterrupt), it won't terminate. I have to kill the signal.  But if I comment/uncomment the following lines (not using the event and doing it the docs way...)

```
comment / worker / if not active.is_set():
uncomment / worker / #if worker_item == None:
comment / main / active.clear()
uncomment / main / #for _ in threads:
                       #q.put(None)
comment / main / except / active.clear()
uncomment / main / except / #for _ in threads:
                                #q.put(None)
```

it does exit with exit code 0. Why?

Why is putting Nones to the queue necessary?
What would be the solution without putting Nones to the queue?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of threads: daemon and non-daemon. By default, all threads are non-daemon. The process is kept alive as long as there is at least one non-daemon thread.

This means that to stop the process, you either have to:

1. stop all of its threads (this is what your commented out code does by using `None` to kick the worker out of the infinite wait in `q.get()`); or
2. make the workers daemon threads, in which case the process will stop as soon as the main thread stops (this will require extra care if you want to ensure the workers have finished their tasks).